# Citrus / Cucumber MessageTracingTestListener doesn't work

Tags: spring, soap, cucumber, citrus-framework

When I try to use the MessageTraceTestListener on Citrus-Cucumber with Spring

```
@Bean
public MessageTracingTestListener messageTracingTestListener() {
    return new MessageTracingTestListener();
}
```

The Error is:

```
[ERROR] Berufbestimmung für Berufe(Berufsuche Service)  Time elapsed: 0.107 s  <<< ERROR!
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Failed to write message trace to filesystem
Caused by: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to write message trace to filesystem
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\citrus-logs\trace\messages\tests\berufssuche.feature:21_20200309_202409.msgs (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
```

Answer (score 0):

Frank - I tried using this as well. I created the folder manually it was trying to write to which got rid of the errors, but even after that it didn't save the request/response messages. As an alternative, have you read about the message store functionality? I tried it and it's working for me. Basically you give the request or response a name then you can use the message store functionality to retrieve it. In my case I have a json response and an xml response that I'm then reading in and parsing through to do some more advanced validations. You can see my example at [Citrus framework: How to make a soap response / citrus variable / citrus function return result available to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539128/citrus-framework-how-to-make-a-soap-response-citrus-variable-citrus-functio). You can also read more about the message store at https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/2.7.8/html/index.html#local-message-store.